# How to avoid using Salable quantity in magento 2

Tags: magento2, quantity, salable

I am using magento 2.4.2-p1.
My site is using Salable quantity functionality.
I don't want to use salable quantity and turn this feature off.
I only want to use Default quantity. How can i do that. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free module to disable scalable quantity by Ampersand.

This module disables the inventory reservation logic introduced as part of MSI
Do check out link below,

https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/2269

Hope this might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Multi source inventory brings this salable quantity logic as it
> reserve a quantity for product sold in inventory reservation table. So
> if you don't want to use this disable all MSI modules and it will
> revert to default quantity logic:

**Module list to be disabled:**

```
Magento_Inventory
Magento_InventoryAdminUi
Magento_InventoryApi
Magento_InventoryBundleProduct
Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryCatalog
Magento_InventorySales
Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi
Magento_InventoryCatalogApi
Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryConfiguration
Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi
Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryImportExport
Magento_InventoryIndexer
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi
Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi
Magento_InventoryProductAlert
Magento_InventoryReservations
Magento_InventoryReservationsApi
Magento_InventoryCache
Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi
Magento_InventorySalesApi
Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi
Magento_InventoryShipping
Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi
Magento_InventorySourceSelection
Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi
Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi
Magento_InventoryElasticsearch
Magento_InventoryExportStockApi
Magento_InventoryReservationCli
Magento_InventoryExportStock
Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl
Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator
Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection
Magento_InventoryRequisitionList
Magento_InventoryGraphQl
Magento_InventoryBundleImportExport
Magento_InventoryBundleProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupAdminUi
Magento_InventoryInStorePickup
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupGraphQl
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingApi
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuoteGraphQl
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuote
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShipping
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupMultishipping
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesAdminUi
Magento_InventoryInStorePickupWebapiExtension
Magento_InventoryCatalogFrontendUi
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi
Magento_InventorySwatchesFrontendUi
Magento_InventoryVisualMerchandiser
Magento_InventoryWishlist
```

**And if you are not using graphql you can disable all graphql modules also to make your project lighter:**

```
Magento_GraphQl
Magento_CmsGraphQl
Magento_EavGraphQl
Magento_CatalogRuleGraphQl
Magento_StoreGraphQl
Magento_CheckoutAgreementsGraphQl
Magento_CatalogGraphQl
Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl
Magento_CompareListGraphQl
Magento_QuoteGraphQl
Magento_DownloadableGraphQl
Magento_CustomerGraphQl
Magento_DirectoryGraphQl
Magento_CustomerDownloadableGraphQl
Magento_CatalogCustomerGraphQl
Magento_GiftMessageGraphQl
Magento_BundleGraphQl
Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl
Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl
Magento_InventoryQuoteGraphQl
Magento_LoginAsCustomerGraphQl
Magento_NewsletterGraphQl
Magento_PaymentGraphQl
Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiGraphQl
Magento_RelatedProductGraphQl
Magento_ReviewGraphQl
Magento_SalesGraphQl
Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQl
Magento_SendFriendGraphQl
Magento_CatalogCmsGraphQl
Magento_SwatchesGraphQl
Magento_TaxGraphQl
Magento_ThemeGraphQl
Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteGraphQl
Magento_PaypalGraphQl
Magento_VaultGraphQl
Magento_WeeeGraphQl
Magento_WishlistGraphQl
PayPal_BraintreeGraphQl
```

**you can try this its safe.**